# Python catch keyboard input in the background and process it

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a python program that is supposed to catch all keyboard input and then depending on the input given emulate a keyboard input
For example, I type the letter a into for example windows notepad
my python program catches this returns an emulated keyboard input for example b
what would be the best way to catch the keyboard input?
I looked into the possibility of using a modified keylogger however I ran into an issue how do I stop for example character a from being typed ?

Comment: This [library](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) may be useful.

Comment: Either you can use a library as @MadyDaby suggested, or you can create a process  (os.spawnl) and log all the keyboard press (using something like pywin32) and process it.

Comment: The libary @MadyDaby has suggested is pretty good however the issue is still that the key for example "a" still is inputed before i can replace it with "b" this can cause an issue as I would be using it in for example a videogame where each keypress cannot be altered once it has been made.

Comment: if you use Windows then you could use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) instead of Python. On Linux you can use similar program [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey). It is created in Python so you can see source code. If you want to write from scratch then you can use mentioned `keyboard` or [pynput.keyboard.Listener](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) with `pynput.keyboard.Controller`

Comment: in some situations you could send `backspace` to remove `a` before you put `b`